# What does a white/yellow rank icon mean

Tags: overwatch

Sometimes (not sure what triggeres it), I see this icon next to my level (instead of the purple rank).

What does it mean?

[image: White/Yellow Icon next to level]

Comment: I've never seen an actual number next to my own level. Are you sure you have?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I can confirm that I sometimes see the yellow icon and sometimes see the level (in purple). No idea what causes which to appear tough. It *might* be related to whether you are in a group or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a top 500 player icon. That came in the Competitive Play update of Overwatch.

You can check this in Overwatch's [blog post](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20167051) of the Competitive Play under the section "Rewards".

The Top 500 icon was confirmed by Blizzard in the Twitter and it was told that a visual bug was recently happening in a [thread on the Overwatch forum](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20745714833) and in a twitter post (linked in the thread).

Comment: Is it only for top 500? Because I would see it next to my level while I was in placement matches. Probably a bug, but it happens.

Comment: Hm... Good question. I assumed that since it was the same icon, it would mean the same thing, but it could be the generic icon of the Competitive Play. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: I found more information about this, updating the answer...

Comment: I think that bug theory is probably the most plausible. There is no way I'm in the Top 500 players. When it's fixed as a Bug in a future patch, we will be sure and I'll accept the answer as confirmed.